# Show that convex compact and closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomoprhic

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

There is a question in the Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis that I am trying to solve. The question asks for

Suppose that $A, B ⊂ \mathbb{R}^2$ are convex, closed, compact, and have nonempty interiors. Then show that they are homeomorphic.

I cannot construct any idea to prove this, can someone help?

Comment: Wlog $B$ is the closed unit ball. If you pick a point $p \in A$ in each direction there is a point with maximal distance. Now map every point $x$ on a line between $p$ and the boundary of $A$ to $dist(x,p)/dist(p,\partial A) \cdot v$, where $v$ is the direction of $x-p$.

Comment: @JulianQuast since we are in R^2, B should be unit disc and why do we need directions?

Comment: You have to rescale the vector $x-p$ in order to land in $B$.

Comment: @JulianQuast $\partial$ is used for what? Sorry, I do not know some notations.

Comment: I had wrong notation, i mean the distance of $p$ to the boundary in the direction of $x$, i.e. the distance of $p$ to the point in $A$ with maximal dist lying on the half line $p \to x$.